# Efficient use of dask with parquet files

Tags: python, dask

I have received a huge (140MM records) dataset and Dask has come in handy but I'm not sure if I could perhaps do a better job. Imagine the records are mostly numeric (two columns are dates), so the process to transform from CSV to parquet was a breeze (dask.dataframe.read_csv('in.csv').to_parquet('out.pq')), but

(i) I would like to use the data on Amazon Athena, so a single parquet file would be nice. How to achieve this? As it stands, Dask saved it as hundreds of files.
(ii) For the Exploratory Data Analysis I'm trying with this dataset, there are certain operations where I need more then a couple of variables, which won't fit into memory so I'm constantly dumping two/three-variable views into SQL, is this code efficient use of dask?

```
mmm = ['min','mean','max']
MY_COLUMNS = ['emisor','receptor','actividad', 'monto','grupo']
gdict = {'grupo': mmm, 'monto': mmm, 'actividad': ['mean','count']}

df = dd.read_parquet('out.pq', columns=MY_COLUMNS).groupby(['emisor','receptor']).agg(gdict)
df = df.compute()
df.columns = ['_'.join(c) for c in df.columns]  # ('grupo','max') -> grupo_max
df.to_sql('er_stats',conn,index=False,if_exists='replace')
```

Reading the file takes about 80 and writing to SQL about 60 seconds.

Comment: You should consider have your data partitioned. With dask you can save directly to S3 (add `storage_options` as parameter) and data could be partitioned with `partition_on`.

Comment: If you need a file only you can use `df = df.repartition(npartitions=1)` before save to parquet.

Comment: So, I've learned a lot about the way dask is meant to be used. Let's rephrase my needs: I have an enormous parquet file I'd like to upload to Amazon Athena via S3. It does NOT need to be a single file after all. But in the process of cleaning up my data I've realized partitioning the data is definitely a good thing and it speeds up all endeavours.

In the beginning, the dataset was 140MM rows and in an ugly pipe separated file. The necessary anonymization (this was sensitive data) produced 18-char long strings in every anonymized row, so the first task was to number-relabel those columns.

Comment: Eventually, in order to be able to hit the data with the sort of queries we needed, a workable data format was necessary. Parquet and SQL/Postgres formats came to mind, but the format transformation became an issue. Time and memory. Always depends on what you need to do with the data...

Crucial fact I've learned today: parquet files can just be uploaded to Athena as parquet folders. 
Added to the fact that dask can efficiently WRITE to s3 parquet files, my whole problem became running dataflow on a machine with enough memory (about 350 Gb RAM) which Amazon provides for about 3USD an hour.

Comment: So imagine this flow: 

df = pd.read_csv('s3://mybucketname/bigfilename.csv') df.to_parquet('s3://mybucketname/bigfilename.parquet')

Answer (score 1):

To reduce the number of partitions, you should either set the blocksize when reading the CSV (preferred), or repartition before writing the parquet. The "best" size depends on your memory and number of workers, but a single partition is probably not possible if your data is "huge". Putting the many partitions into a single file is also not possible (or, rather, not implemented), because dask writes in parallel and there would be no way of knowing where in the file the next part goes before the previous part is finished. I could imagine writing code to read in successive dask-produced parts and streaming them into a single output, it would not be hard but perhaps not trivial either.

> writing to SQL about 60 seconds

This suggests that your output is still quite large. Is SQL the best option here? Perhaps writing again to parquet files would be possible.

Comment: Yup, it's 1 Gb. Clearly not the best option, but I'm more used to this for further manipulations, not quite dask literate enough to perform the same operations as in sql. Will try postgres too.